# How to stop showing the dialer when calling from an app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app to control an electrical circuit via GSM.

This app sends a signal as a call or message to a GSM module connected to an electrical circuit that will break the circuit according to the signal received.

What I want is that when I click a button in the Activity, a GSM call should be made to a particular number which is hardcoded, **but should not invoke the dialer UI**.
The dialer UI needs to be replaced with some progress image for some seconds.

Anyone please help me.
I completed all the electrical and electronics circuits for this project, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: I have used ACTION_CALL..

Answer (score 0):

Use **ACTION_CALL** instead of **ACTION_DIAL**.
But it requires an additional permission: `CALL_PHONE`.